# Hypothesis testing on a fraction of the entire population

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sample-size

I am conducting an [A/B test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) to observe the difference between the means of the number of daily actions that users perform. For instance, suppose the test runs for $T$ days, then there are $A_1, \dots, A_T$ and $B_1, \dots B_T$ daily number of actions for each group, respectively, and I would compare $\mu_A = \frac1T\sum_{i=1}^T A_i$ with $\mu_B = \frac1T\sum_{i=1}^T B_i$:
$$
H_0: \mu_A = \mu_B \\
H_1: \mu_A \not= \mu_B
$$

Now, assume that I only have access to a random, but unbiased fraction $f$ of all the users. That is, if there were $N$ users (roughly $\frac{N}{2}$ in each group), I can only observe the effect from $f \cdot N$ users ($\approx f\cdot\frac{N}{2}$ in each group).

My question is: how to approach this problem so that to account for this $f$ in the statistical hypothesis test? The immediate intuition is that since there are fewer users in each group, the test must run longer to for the conclusion to become significant.

Comment: This sounds like a blend of a finite population and a sample size calculation.

Comment: Thank you, @Dave -- can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: There are corrections one can make when the population is finite, and, while I have never done this, I suspect they can be applied to sample size calculations like we do for abstract/infinite populations.

Comment: all hypothesis testing is based on having a fraction of the whole population; if you have the whole population you do not need to do hypothesis testing (as you have observed the whole population...) so the scenario you describe is exactly the scenario for all hypothesis testing.

Comment: "how to account for this f" the fraction basically determines sample size in both of your samples, which has direct effect on things like p-values, width of confidence intervals, etc. Often a power analysis is conducted apriori to determine how large of a sample (ie what fraction of population) needs to be sampled in order to identify a given effect size